# Load the Jquery Library on every Ajax Call?

Tags: jquery, ajax, getscript

i am using infinite scroll plugin in wordpress to load the new posts when users scoll down to the page. now i have the gallery effect that comes through the Jquery. for that purpose i detect the ajax request in the browser and load that jquery library effect again.I am using following code

```
$( document ).ajaxSuccess(function() {
  $.getScript( "ajax/test1.js");
  $.getScript( "ajax/test2.js");
});
```

but that can load the library multiple time on first ajax call due to this browser gets crashed.
i tried using **`return false`** afetr the libraries but result is the same
Any Hint for this situation???

Comment: it's easiest to include the scripts once from the html, i.e. `<script src="ajax/test1.js"></script>` what prevents you from doing this?

Comment: try this: http://goo.gl/YjdXjY

Comment: @EruPenkman i am wanted to refresh the jquery library after every ajax call completed successfully

Comment: You probably don't have to reload the scripts in order to refresh the library affect. I don't know which plugin you are using but try calling its methods again rather than loading the script.